# Compile error on abstract class/function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, abstract-class

I'm having a weird error (missing ';', string class not recognized, etc) on an C++ abstract class (which other classes need to inherit and instanciate). Also I want derived classes to be forced to implement the abstract class methods - hence the pure virtual = 0.

Below is my abstract class definition.

Drawable.h:

```
#ifndef __myns__managers__Drawable_h__
#define __myns__managers__Drawable_h__

#include <string>

namespace myns
{
    namespace managers
    {
        class Drawable;
    }
}

namespace myns
{
    namespace managers
    {
        class Drawable
        {
            public:
                virtual float getX() = 0;
                virtual float getY() = 0;
                virtual string getImageFilePath() = 0;
            protected:
                int drawableId;

        };
    }
}

#endif
```

By my relative knowledge of C++ I guess that's everything ok, right? But when I compile on VS 2010 it gives me a bunch of compile errors - shown below.

How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

VS Build Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: InteractiveMembranes_vc10, Configuration: X86 Debug Win32 ------
1>  OutputManager.cpp
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getImageFilePath'
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2433: 'interactivemembranes::managers::Drawable::string' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): warning C4183: 'getImageFilePath': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2253: 'interactivemembranes::managers::Drawable::getImageFilePath' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
1>  Application.cpp
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getImageFilePath'
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2433: 'interactivemembranes::managers::Drawable::string' : 'virtual' not permitted on data declarations
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): warning C4183: 'getImageFilePath': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'
1>(project dir)\managers\drawable.h(23): error C2253: 'interactivemembranes::managers::Drawable::getImageFilePath' : pure specifier or abstract override specifier only allowed on virtual function
1>  Generating Code...
1>  Compiling...
1>  TestPersistence.cpp
1>  Generating Code...
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to qualify `string`:

```
virtual std::string getImageFilePath() = 0;
```

`string` is in the `std` namespace, not in the global one. There's also the option of `using namespace std;` which will import the namespace into the global one, but **don't do it, especially in headers**. I'm just presenting it as an option, but you should always prefer qualifying the names.

EDIT: As Als pointed out, you can import only what you need: `using std::string;`. I'd still prefer qualifying the name though.

Comment: *Using declaration* is more convenient in such a case, `using std::string;`.

Comment: OMG, true story. Duh! Solved it, thanks. Newbie C++ programmer being newbie.